# Pick a word from the block

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an address like `546 Ave 13 units` <-- this.

There are multiple values in the address

```
546 Ave 14 unit
546 Ave 15 unit
546 Ave 16 unit
547 Ave 19 unit
546 Ave 22 unit
```

from all of this.

I need to create a column that consists of only values like

```
13 units
14 unit
15 unit
16 unit
17 unit
```

from that block.

I'm a beginner, can anybody can help me with that?

Comment: You really need regex to handle this properly, which SQL Server (presumably your database) does not really support.  You may want to handle this outside of SQL Server and then reimport your data.

Comment: `replace(the_column, '546 Ave ', '')`?

Comment: The expected result doesn't match the sample data, or? (546 Ave 14 unit => 13 units?)

Comment: No streets or boulevards? Always 3 digit numbers? Sample data should include the tricky cases too. Otherwise you may end up with a query that works for the simple case, but will fail later, during production.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select right('546 Ave 14 unit'
             , charindex(' ' , '546 Ave 14 unit'
                         , charindex(' ','546 Ave 14 unit'))
                         + charindex(' ','546 Ave 14 unit')-1)
```

The logic behind it is like this:

`charindex(' ','546 Ave 14 unit')` This will give you the location of the first blank space.
`charindex(' ' , '546 Ave 14 unit', charindex(' ','546 Ave 14 unit'))` This will give you the location of the second blank space.
`-1` i so it does not take that blank space in consideration. 
And the `right` function will give you the string after the certain index in string and we have found where that index is by finding the index of the second blank space.

There is another option:

```
select parsename(replace('546 Ave 14 unit',' ','.'),1)  
       + ' ' 
       + parsename(replace('546 Ave 14 unit',' ','.'),2)
```

`parsname` will return a part after the '.' starting from rihght. So parsname('word1.word2', 1) will return word2 and parsname('word1.word2', 2) will return word2. That is why we have replaced blank spaces with full stops by using `replace` function before using parsname function.

Answer (score 0):

If it always ends with "[number] unit" you can do it like this

```
declare @text varchar(64)
set @text = '546 Ave 14 unit'

select RIGHT(@text,PATINDEX ('%[0-9] %' , Reverse(@text)))
```

But your requirement is not clear yet